# How to log all uncaught exceptions in java using log4j

Tags: java, exception, logging, log4j

I want to log the exceptions in my server side java program.
Is there any way to catch all exceptions that have not been caught using an existing try catch?

I thought about doing a try catch in my main executor and log the exception the catch but I got a problem: exceptions on other threads haven't been caught.

Comment: so ... you catch all Exceptions, yet not all Exceptions are caught?

Comment: Not not all are caught -> Uncaught exceptions should be logged

Comment: have you tried aop?

Answer (score 3):

Each thread can have an [`UncaughtExceptionHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html), which is called when an exception reaches the bottom of the thread's call stack. The default implementation prints a message on the standard error.

You can change the default handler with:

```java
  private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler((t, e) -> {
      logger.warn("Uncaught exception in thread {}.", t, e);
    });
```

Comment: That looks good, thank you. But there is no general way to handle exceptions in a java program?
This way I have to add the handler to each Thread I create?

Comment: The default `UncaughtExceptionHandler` applies to **all threads**, not just the current one.